# copy the next column values and paste to the previous column

Tags: excel

I have 20 columns of values in excel sheet and each has two 12 rows, i want to cut the values of the second column values and paste in to the first column 13th row and then cut the values of third column and paste in first column 25 row and so on

Answer (score 0):

Instead of cutting and pasting it can be easier to create beside a new table with the desired layout using formula
(reference to the desired cell). You can then copy/paste value .